# How to create a software with gdal docker image and run it with Java GUI?

Tags: java, c++, docker

I have a software which is written in C/C++ and there a couple of python3 modules. The front-end GUI is made in Java-Swing. It opens up images too in Java Swing environment.

The C/C++ use libraries such as libtiff, gdal, proj4, gsl etc. The path to this libraries is given when the program starts, which is Java GUI, which in turn calls each C/C++ binary or python3 modules using ProcessBuilder.

How do I build a docker image so that everytime, a use launches the program, all the binaries/python scripts are available to the Java GUI. I want to make the software portable with all the dependencies.

I cannot imagine the pieces connecting together.

Comment: It's tricky at best to run a desktop GUI application out of a Docker container.  You need a Linux-compatible display setup (extra software on Windows or MacOS), you need special configuration to access data files on the host system, and the configuration to make the display actually work is extra fiddly.  I'd suggest a different packaging setup.

Comment: What if I have GUI seperately and call my code out of docker. The problem I have is that the code I have in docker should operate on the data given by the user.